# Таблица истинности для выражения [javascript]

Tags: javascript

Привет

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Таблица истинности</title>
</head>
<body>
<script Language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function ButtonClick() {
  mm = document.forms.myform.input_field.value;
  document.write("Таблица истинности выражения: ", mm)
  document.write("<br>");
  for(var i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
  for(var j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
  for(var k = 0; k <= 1; k++)
{  
  a = i;
  b = j;
  c = k
  m = mm;
        m = m.split (/a/).join (a).    // Поиск и замена символов на значения
        split (/b/).join (b).
        split (/c/).join (c);

        m = m.split ('!0').join ('\t').    // инверсия
        split ('!1').join ('!0').
        split ('\t').join ('!1');

        m = m.split (/!/).join ("");  // поиск и удаление знака !   
    var x = 1;
    while (m[x + 1] != undefined) {
        if (m[x] == '&') {
            if ((m[x - 1] == '1') && (m[x + 1] == '1')) {
                var arr = m.split ('');
                arr[x-1] = 1;
                arr.splice((x-1), 2)
                m = arr.join ('');
                arr = [];
                x--;
                }
            else {
                var arr = m.split ('');
                arr[x-1] = 0;
                arr.splice((x-1), 2)
                m = arr.join ('');
                arr = [];
                x--;
            }
        }
        x++;
    }

    var x = 1;
    while (m[x + 1] != undefined) {
        if (m[x] == '|') {
            if ((m[x-1] == 0) && (m[x+1] == 0)) {
                var arr = m.split ('');
                arr[x-1] = 0;
                arr.splice((x-1), 2)
                m = arr.join ('');
                arr = [];
                x--;
                }
            else {
                var arr = m.split ('');
                arr[x-1] = 1;
                arr.splice((x-1), 2)
                m = arr.join ('');
                arr = [];
                x--;
            }
        }
        x++;
    }

  document.write("| " ,a, " | " ,b, " | " ,c, " | ", m, " | ");
  document.write("<br>");
}
  }

</script>
<h4>Введите выражение:</h4>
<form name="myform">
<input type="text" name="input_field" size="25">
<p><input type="button" style="width:170Px;height:25Px" value="Составить таблицу" OnClick="ButtonClick()"></p>
<cite>При заполнении используйте операции: &,|,!</cite>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

В данном скрипте вводится строка, затем находятся операнды с "не", заменяются на противоположные, затем оператор "!" удаляется. Следующие два цикла while нужны: 1 цикл ищет & и заменяет оператор со смежными операндами на 1 или 0 в соответствии с правилами логического умножения; 2 цикл похожий, только ищет | и заменяет на 1 или 0 тоже в соответствии с правилами логического сложения. Так вот все вроде бы хорошо делается, но в циклах while неправильно выполняются условия (if). Пример: встречается в строке 0&1, вроде бы условие не выполняется (см. код) и оператор & с операндами должен замениться на 0, но он ПОЧЕМУ-ТО заменяется на 1. Я так до сих пор и не понял почему это происходит. Помогите понять, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.splice((x-1), 2)
```

Я не до конца понял логику, но эта строчка делает следующее: **возвращает** массив из двух элементов и **оставляет** все оставшееся (в вашем случае - последний элемент). В 0&1 это будет 1, который и присвоится m. Теперь по остальному:

```
m.split (/a/).join (a)
```

/a/ в данном случае не преобразится в переменную a:

```
var a = 'x';
var m = 'zzzxzzz';
console.log(m.split(/a/));
> ["zzzxzzz"]  // ничего не поменялось
```

Замену делать каноничней так (вы пытаетесь разобрать ее через регэксп в массив символов, ниже объясню, почему массив вам не нужен):

```
'Нина стерва'.replace('стерва', 'душка');
```

Но даже если бы все было в порядке, эта операция не принесла бы вам ничего, просто разобрав и собрав строчку:

```
var x = 'aaaaaazaaaazaaaaz';
var split = x.split('z'); // ["aaaaaa", "aaaa", "aaaa", ""]
split.join('z'); // "aaaaaazaaaazaaaaz"
```

> Следующие два цикла while нужны: 1 цикл ищет & и заменяет оператор со смежными операндами на 1 или 0 в соответствии с правилами логического умножения; 2 цикл похожий, только ищет | и заменяет на 1 или 0 тоже в соответствии с правилами логического сложения.

Во-первых, нужен только один цикл:

```
while (m[x + 1] != undefined) {
    if(m[x] == '&') {
       //
    } else if (m[x] == '|') {
       //
    }
}
```

Во-вторых, сравнивать с undefined - это неверный путь. В яваскрипте у массивов и строк есть свойство length, которое позволит преоразовать while в обычный for.
Теперь про строки: в условиях вы свободно обращаетесь со строками, как с массивами

```
while (m[x] != undefined)
```

Но во всех остальных местах зачем-то бьете строки на массивы символов. Этого делать не нужно, потому что строка[индекс] будет работать одинаков как в полученном массиве, так и в исходной строке.

```
if ((m[x-1] == 0) && (m[x+1] == 0)) {
    var arr = m.split (''); // получили (с точки зрения последующего кода) почти то же самое
    arr[x-1] = 0; // это легко можно было бы сделать и в строке. А еще вы уже сравнивали x-1 с нулем, и он уже был равен нулю.
    arr.splice((x-1), 2)
    m = arr.join (''); // даже если бы мы arr состоял из двух элементов, m бы присваивалось что-то вроде 0& или 1|
    arr = []; // абсолютно ненужная операция
    x--; // этого бы не было, если бы мы запихнули все в цикл. Хотя я до конца не понял логику, и, возможно, while (x < m.length) был бы правильней.
}
```

Следующее совсем некритично, но засоряет глобальную область:

```
a = i;
b = j;
c = k
m = mm;
```

Все эти переменные (в отличие от объявленных с помощью var) будут видны для других функций, скриптов и доступны через window.a, window['b']. Для небольших скриптов это не несет никакой угрозы, но дебаг js - дело не самое приятное и лучше как минимум подстраховаться.

Касательно таблицы истинности: я не совсем понял, какая таблица истинности строится (точнее для какой/каких операций), но, похоже, ввод пользователя там и не очень нужен (разве что выбор операции).
Последнее: любые значения в коде легко отслеживать с помощью console.log():

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    console.log(i); // 0, 1, 2, ... 19
}
```

Этот вывод можно подсмотреть в консоли браузера (в хроме - ctrl + shift + j).

Comment: Хм, я попробовал ввести 0&40, выводит 40. Не понимаю почему?
Отдельно в файле другом тестил: var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
var x = 1; arr.splice((x-1), 2);
Удаляет же цифры 2,3 после 1

Comment: @thejadefalcon моя консоль, прямо вот сейчас

    [я] var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]; var x = 1; arr.splice((x-1), 
    [консоль] [1, 2]
    [консоль] event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.min.js:59
    [я] arr
    [консоль] [3, 4, 5]

А еще есть документация https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Я два цикла while сделал потому, что мне нужно в соответствии с приоритетом сделать замены, т.е. сначала & а потом |

Разбиваю строку в массив, потому что в дальнейшем мне нужно будет заменять в массиве. Я пробовал заменять в строке, фигня получается неправильная.

Comment: Вроде бы получилось все правильно сделать. arr.splice(x, 2); теперь стала такой, и после каждой замены пришлось добавить continue; Сам не понял почему его пришлось добавить, но добавил и заработало